# A simple code in Selenium doesn't work

Tags: c#, selenium

So, I have this simple code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://someurl");
    try
    {
        IWebElement search = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=comboInput']"));
        search.SendKeys(".");
        IWebElement searchtext = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='itext']"));
        searchtext.SendKeys(".");
        IWebElement searchsend = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='buttonArea']/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")).Click();
        Console.WriteLine("Did it");
    }

    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nope");
    }



}
```

}

I have no idea what's wrong with this code. The error is :

cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Iwebelement'

And the problem is with `IWebDriver driver`

Note : If this is a stupid question and I'm missing some kind of obvious fix, let me know. But I honestly can't figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: You should be aware of OOPS... Learn OOPS first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
 IWebElement searchsend = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='buttonArea']/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")).Click();
```

You're assigning the result to `searchsend` but [Click](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Click.htm) 'returns' `void`.

Comment: How can I use click then? I'm quite new to Selenium, would be awesome if you could help me out.

Comment: @TheEnthusiast That is an entirely different question.

Comment: I'm sure I will find it somewhere then. Thanks for this tho !